# Is it possible to have two different versions of collabnet svn on the same windows machine?

Tags: svn

If so how would I go about setting that up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use two batch files `svn1` and `svn2` that call the different installations. For example:

```
REM svn1.cmd
call /path/to/svn/version-x/svn.exe %*
```

...and:

```
REM svn2.cmd
call /path/to/svn/version-y/svn.exe %*
```

If you place these batch files inside your PATH, you can use both versions of svn easily.